# Was/Were - Singular or Plural?

Tags: singular-subject-and-verb

Was is generally accepted as singular - 'a dog was in the garden', were, plural - 'some dogs were in the garden.

So why is 'You was in the garden' so wrong, (you were in the garden) but have to be 'you were in the garden, singular *and* plural? It seems to be restricted to only the noun 'you', which could be singular *or* plural - and in a lot of cases, that fact remains hidden.

Comment: It seems wrong because it is 'generally accepted', and similarly for 'they' used in the singular. It's also 'generally accepted' that conjugation is illogical too: I go, you go, he **goes**, we go, you go, they go.

Comment: **Third person** singular 'was', third person plural 'were'. **Second person** happens to be 'were' for both.

Comment: Questions asking **why** grammar rules are the way they are, will probably have no answer.

Comment: Look up “thou” for some relevant information.

Comment: Per @Peter, the word *you* started life as plural.

Comment: But @Centaurus says it even better.

Comment: @KateBunting - 'happens to be' doesn't really give much of a clue.

Comment: I can't tell you why the language has evolved that way, I can only tell you the facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer to this question in a related but different one. As [this answer explains](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/22197/480127), "you" was originally the plural form of "thou". Hence "you were" included a plural verb "were" agreeing with a plural noun "you".

As the language evolved "you" started being used to refer to singular individuals, and the verb "were" came along with it, now also being singular (in that particular context).

Comment: So, 'you' is both singular and plural. We know that. Why isn't it universal in its use?

Comment: You're probably being confused by the fact that _be_ is the only verb in English that marks plural in past tense: _I went, we went, she went, they went_. But _I was, we were, she was, they were_. Other than  _be_, singular and plural are identical in the past tense. In other words, _be_ is already by far the most irregular verb in English, so that's why it's not universal in its usage. This is a fact about the auxiliary verb _be_, not about singular or plural.