# Which one should I use thy/thine

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammaticality

I want to form a sentence which says"I am yours" in a way that I replace "yours" with thy/thine, but I have no idea which one is correct. I've read that each one of these is used depending on what word comes after thy/thine, but in this case "yours" is the last word in the sentence, therefore it isn't followed by anything. I also have the same question for the sentence "I am hers". What word is going to be a proper replacement for "hers", given the fact that it is also the last word?

Comment: I suggest using them in the same way as "my" and "mine".

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question about a 'replacement for "hers"'. You seem to believe that there was a form of "hers" similar to "thy/thine"?

Comment: In a way that thy/thine are used for possessive form of "your". What word would be used for "hers" is what I meant.

Comment: hers-thine; her-thy

Comment: There's no alternative to 'hers' that I am aware of, the way that 'thy/thine' is an archaic alternative for 'your/yours'. One says "It is her thing" or "The thing is hers".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "thy" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-does-thy-mean)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yes there is. Thy/thine = her/hers. In full *I/me/my/mine = thou/thee/thy/thine = she/her/her/hers*.

Comment: Thanks @WS2 - that's what I was trying to say, but you said it better (and more completely).

Comment: @WS2 - You misunderstand me. "thy/thine" is an archaic alternative for "your/yours", not "my/mine". There is no alternative for using "her/hers" that refers to the third person singular feminine, the way that both "you/yours" and "thy/thine" refer to the second person singular.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm supposing that WS2 is indicating that these are the corresponding forms, not that they are interchangeable.

Comment: @SNLacy Yes that is what I was attempting to do.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin My apologies for misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 12):

***Thy*** and ***thine*** are archaic forms corresponding to ***your*** and ***yours*** respectively. Use ***thy*** where you would use ***your*** (but see note at end of answer) and ***thine*** where you would use ***yours***.

***Her*** and ***hers*** do not have alternate/archaic forms. ***Her*** is used as a possessive the same way ***my*** or ***your*** is, and ***hers*** is used like ***mine*** or ***yours***.

(Note: if the noun placed after ***thy*** begins with a vowel sound, use ***thine*** instead: ***thy book***, but ***thine eyes***. Archaically, the same was done with ***my*** and ***mine***, but this is no longer common usage outside of some poetic use.)

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has an article that explains to you the grammar of [***thou*** and all its forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou), and what clarifies your query is that ***thine*** can be used:

> as an adjective before a vowel or ***as a possessive pronoun***

Here are a few examples which will free you from any hesitation to us ***thine*** in that position:

> - I am ***thine***, save me (Ps. 119:94 KJV)
> - My lord, O king, according to thy saying, I am *thine*, and all that I have. (1 Kings 20:4 KJV)
> - for all that is in the heaven and in the earth is ***thine*** (1 Chr. 29:11 KJV)

And the biblical examples are many.

Let's look at Shakespeare:

> - This is the palace of the fearful king,
>   And this the regal seat: possess it, York;
>   For this is ***thine*** and not King Henry's heirs. ([Henry VI (Pt 3), Act I](https://www.infoplease.com/primary-sources/books-plays/william-shakespeare/william-shakespeare-henry-vi-pt-3-act-i))

> Old lad, I am ***thine*** own. ([Titus Andronicus, Act 4, Scene 2](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/titus/titus.4.2.html))

[Shelley](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Complete_Poetry_of_Percy_Bysshe_Shel/vtGSDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Till%20the%20sinking%20of%20the%20world,%20I%20am%20thine%20and%20thou%20art%20mine,%20%27Till%20in%20ruin%20death%20is%20hurled%22&pg=PT1825&printsec=frontcover) uses it too:

> - Till the sinking of the world,
>    I am ***thine*** and thou art mine,
>    'Till in ruin death is hurled.