# Why "thine heart" but "thy whole heart"?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives, phonetics, archaicisms, early-modern-english

I have somehow picked up the use of the two different forms "thy/thine" from the KJV Bible, and I thought I knew the rule. Use ***thy*** before consonants and ***thine*** before vowels or before words starting with the sound [h].

There are plenty of instances of [***thine heart***](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/search.php?hs=1&q=thine%20heart) or [***thine hands***](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/search.php?hs=1&q=thine%20hands) in the KJV for example, and while doing a translation from Greek into KJV style English, I almost went along with  ***thine whole heart***, since *whole*, just like *hand* and *heart*, starts with the same sound. Right? Well, on second thought I just thought I'd check to see if I find any instances of it, and I was surprised to find:

> If ***thy whole body*** therefore be full of light, having no part dark, the whole shall be full of light, as when the bright shining of a candle doth give thee light. [KJV](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Luke-11-36/)

I disagree with [sites](https://findanyanswer.com/when-to-use-thy-or-thine) that say

> ** "Thy" and "thine" are archaic forms corresponding to "your" and "yours" respectively. Use "thy" where you would use "your" (but see note at end of answer) and "thine" where you would use "yours".

because it is very clear to me that *thine* can definitely mean both *your* and *yours*. One answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/406437/which-one-should-i-use-thy-thine/409871) from the ELU agrees with me, but it does not fully address the phonetic problem of words starting with the sound [h].

Does anyone know the rule? Is it actually a phonetic rule, or an orthographic one?

Comment: It's a phonetic rule, but the phonetics may have changed between the original writing and the present - for example, at the time of writing, "heart" may not have had the initial aspiration (h), and a modern ear may well have heard "art".

Comment: So no difference in pronunciation between **thine heart** and **thine art**?

Comment: (_It also may not be_ temporally _variant, but_ geographically _- even today, there are places where you'll hear words starting with an **h** pronounced without the **h** and/or with a glottal stop._)

Comment: In effect, no. There might be a minor difference in pronunciation per my parenthetical, in that you might have heard more of a glottal stop in _thine heart_ (_thine 'eart_, to represent it in dialect) than in _thine art_.

Comment: The King James Bible is written in Early Modern English - as such, the leading h is often dropped in words like heart, but words like whole would be pronounced with a [ʍ]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English Presumably the best way to tell if an h is being dropped in a particular occurrence of the word is if they use thy or thine!

Comment: Would h's be dropped on stressed syllables, or only unstressed?  If the latter, perhaps the spelling is a subtle clue that the word THINE would be stressed, rather than heart?

Comment: @supercat: Rather doubtful, since you can find instances both of **thine heart** and of **thy heart** in the KJV.

Comment: @fev: If one looks at which spelling is used where, is there any correlation with situations where the phrase means "YOUR heart" [as opposed to someone else's]  or where it means "your HEART" [as opposed to some other part of the body]?  If usage is based upon word stress, I would expect "thy heart" for the former, and "thine heart" for the latter.

Comment: Aside: this feels suspiciously related to why some people still insist on needing **an** history lesson, despite that many modern English speakers feel that's **a** historic anachronism, and a strange one at that.

Comment: @Matthew: So you feel that history might be able to explain this flexibility?

Comment: Well... yes, though I think you may have missed the joke . Certain pedants insists on using "an" with "history" and related words on the premise that these words start with a vowel. Many (most?) modern speakers would disagree. "Thy" vs. "thine" would appear to *mostly* follow the same precedent, i.e. not considering "h" a consonant. (Except for inconsistencies. Those might just be... inconsistent, possibly even accidental. Perhaps the shift was already in progress.)

Comment: It may also be worth noting that there are other instances of "thy heart" (Cornelius' [Three Kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Kings) comes immediately to mind, for one), suggesting that the shift of "h" from silent to aspirated consonant was already under way while "thy" and relatives were still in use.

Comment: @Matthew: I did get the joke but I was more intrigued by the historical factor you brought up. In fact, what you said, "Perhaps the shift was already in progress" might explain the inconsistencies in the KJV. I hadn't thought about that, so thanks.

Comment: @Michael: Usually people who use "an" in front of "h-" words only do so when the initial syllable is unstressed - so they'll say "a history" but "an historic event".

Comment: @fev, I think the inconsistencies in the KJV are mainly due to the several translators of that work having differing opinions, such as whether to render the Greek _pneuma hagion_ as "Holy Spirit" or "Holy Ghost"--both exist in the KJV.

Comment: @RobJarvis: Again, rather doubtful. In my answer to this question, you can see that both uses occur even in the same verse: "But if thou hast gone aside to another instead of _**thy husband**_, and if thou be defiled, and some man have lain with thee beside _**thine husband**_." That's the same translator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jeff Zeitlin, the rule was phonetic, it's just that initial *h*'s are highly prone to elision/deletion. The [Wikipedia article on *thou*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou#Grammar) says that *thine* was used before nouns beginning with a vowel (sound), or ‘before nouns beginning in the letter *h*, which was usually silent’. The article also gives an example where the *h* is silent in 'heart':

> *thine eyes* and *mine heart*, which was pronounced as *mine art*

In KJV, we also find [*thine house*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PcYXO_-Us0AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=KJV&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22thine%20house%22&f=false), so it seems the use of *thy/thine* with words beginning with *h* was pretty irregular.

According to *English Historical Linguistics* by De Gruyter Mouton (edited by Laurel J. Brinton *et al*), ‘at the beginning of the period in 1500’, *thy* was used before consonants and *thine* before a vowel or <h> + vowel. It goes on to say that ‘[i]n case of silent word-initial <h>, as in *honour*, *host* or *habit*, we find *mine/thine*, and also before a pause.’

It further adds:

> This usage changes in the 16th century. “By 1600, *my* and *thy* are almost without exception the forms used before consonants, while before vowels *my* and *mine* are in free variation [in simple words, *interchangeable*], as are *thy* and *thine*: **Shakespeare has both *thine eyes* and *thy eye*, both
> *mine own* and *my own*”** [emphasis mine] (Barber 1997: 152). The following [example] (4) [...] from Shakespeare’s plays (see Busse 2002: 224) underline[s] this seemingly random patterning of variants within a single line of text, as they defy the neat distribution usually given in reference works:
>
> (4) *In **thine** own person answer **thy** abuse* (1590/91 *The Second Part of King Henry the Sixth* II.i.40)

(p735)

Comment: Your answer makes sense, just as @JeffZeitlin's comments seemed to elucidate the mystery pretty well. Yet occurrences of both "thine heart" and "thy heart" in the KJV seem to leave me into a slight confusion. However, while using myself this language, I will probably use the rule you mentioned...

Comment: Your confusion should be accepted as entirely natural as clearly the writers of KJV suffered from the same confusion...

Comment: @fev KJV was commissioned in 1604 and published in 1611. It's entirely reasonable that it should be subject to "free variation" as it was written in the vernacular of the time.

Comment: Try reading "In thine own person answer thy abuse" *aloud.* (and as if you are speaking in the middle of a raging argument that is going to end in a fight.) Then try the other permutations of "thy" and "thine". If you still don't know why Shakespeare wrote what he wrote, you don't understand how speech rhythms work.

Comment: VERY INTERESTING.
But add to this that the KJV bible was written by more then one person.
That really complicates things.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure of the explanation for "thy whole body".

The KJV (at least, the version indexed at the website that you linked to) uses both *my, thy, a* and *mine, thine, an* before words starting with /h/. Here are some examples of [*thy heart*](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Ecclesiastes-11-9/) and [*my heart*](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Song-of-Solomon-4-9/). Likewise, we find both *[thy head](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Proverbs-1-9/)* and *[thine head](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Jeremiah-2-37/)*, *[a house](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Mark-3-25/)* and *[an house](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/2-Samuel-5-11/).*

So the presence or absence of /n/ in these [determiners](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/determiners) apparently does not simply follow a consistent rule according to the current pronunciation of words starting with the sound /h/.

I have not found any rule for when to use one form versus the other. My guess is that it was originally non-standardized, and unlike other parts of the spelling and grammar of the King James Version, never ended up being regularized.

I think there is probably not always a one-to-one correspondence between the use of *n* spellings in the KJV and whether the writer would have pronounced the word with [h] or not (that is, I don't think we can definitely conclude that whenever *a/my/thy house/head/heart...* etc. is written, the writer was intending to represent a pronunciation with [h], and whenever *an/mine/thine house/head/heart...* etc. as written, the author was intending to represent a pronunciation without [h]). Actually, although vowel-initial words seem to greatly prefer *n* spellings, there are a few instances in the KJV where vowel-initial words seem to take the n-less spelling, such as Deuteronomy 12:17 ("[thy oil](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Deuteronomy-12-17/)") or Leviticus 27:6 ("thy estimation"). Unless these are just accidents/misprints, this suggests to me that the usage of *n* forms was not based solely on pronunciation, since I doubt *thy oil* or *thy estimation* was pronounced with [h] or any other consonant sound at the start of the second word.

Comment: You are actually right, I checked in my BibleWorks program and indeed, it says "thy heart"! That discourages my attempts to get a good grip of the rule :(

Comment: I regret I can't accept two answers. Both complement each other and I appreciate the information provided very much. I had no idea that it was so flexible, but then it confirms my intuition of the "fluidity" of the English language. This is one virtue my logical mind had to get accustomed with when I came to the UK. I find it fascinating. Thank you both!

Comment: The KJV was written and edited by a lot of people, rather quickly, reusing earlier texts where possible even if they used different conventions, so it is very inconsistent in a lot of things.

Answer (score 4):

I appreciated both answers to this questions, but I somehow wanted to find evidence or some record of this "irregularity" of use of ***thy/thine***. I have found a source that seems to know what it is talking about, so I thought to add it as an answer:

> In a deliberately archaic style, the possessive forms are used as the genitive before words beginning with a vowel sound (for example, *thine eyes*) similar to how *an* is used instead of *a* in *an eye*. ***This practice is followed irregularly in the King James Bible but is more regular in earlier literature, such as the Middle English texts of Geoffrey Chaucer.***  (source: [History of English](https://www.docsity.com/pt/history-of-english-23/4774158/) and [tagged wiki](http://taggedwiki.zubiaga.org/new_content/1c8de8abae6c49fb7eb8a9ed05148c82)) - probably the first source quoted the second here.

Another [site](https://academickids.com/encyclopedia/index.php/Thou) adds to this quotation:

> it may have emerged as a later nicety.

A [private site](https://wmjas.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/how-to-use-thee-thou-and-other-king-james-pronouns/) made this interesting observation:

> *Thy* is used before a word beginning with a consonant, and *thine* before a word beginning with a vowel. *Either form is acceptable for words beginning with the letter “h”*; ***thine*** *is generally more common for h-words in the Bible,* ***but both forms are used, sometimes even in the same verse*** (for example, Numbers 5:20 includes both “thy husband” and “thine husband”).

On [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WVY9AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA223&lpg=PA223&dq=possessive%20thy/thine%20before%20words%20starting%20with%20h&source=bl&ots=dr5s4z6Rg4&sig=ACfU3U250_O8j7--r21IwufEQDlr4b_5Cw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1n8CzxoXxAhWz8-AKHWfcBAIQ6AEwEHoECA8QAw#v=onepage&q=possessive%20thy%2Fthine%20before%20words%20starting%20with%20h&f=false) (in a book with the title *Linguistic Variation in the Shakespeare Corpus*) I found this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So it makes sense that people who studied the history of this language were aware of this irregularity around towards the end of the 16th century, but no one investigated its causes. Guess it will remain a mystery.