# Can I use word "Thou", "Thee", "Thy" and "Thine" like following

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

Firstly I have researched about those words, [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4058) really help me understand their meanings.

So I believe that those words are singular form of You, you, your and yours respectively.

Furthermore, "Thou" is a subject form while "thee" is the object form. so could someone tell me if I can use them as following.

***Who are thou?*** instead of **Who are you?** 
***I have come to see thee.*** instead of **I have come to see you.** 
***What are thy future dreams?*** instead of **What are your future dreams?** 
***I believe this pen is thine.*** instead of **I believe this pen is yours.**

Thanks.

Comment: The important piece of information missing from your question is in what situation do you want to use these expressions? In everyday speech or in the novel you are writing. And by "can use" do you mean are they grammatically correct, or if you will be considered to be speaking "normal modern English" by native speakers?

Comment: I ask because the four words you mention are seen as archaic and almost always feel like they are coming from Medieval or Shakespeare times.

Comment: @katatahito I do not intent to use them in day to day life, I am just asking if they are grammatically correct. Thank you.

Comment: _Thou_ requires a specific form of the verb, which always ends in _-((e)s)t_ (e.g., _thou art_, _thou wert_, _thou canst_, _thou thinkest_, etc.), so the first sentence is not grammatical. The rest are fine. Since they are so archaic, however, you should be aware that it’s frequently not just a matter of substituting one word for another – in order for it to seem natural, you’d have to emulate other grammatical features of older English as well, such as different vocabulary and inversion instead of _do_-support in questions (“Camest thou yestereve?” instead of “Did you come last night?”).

Comment: "Thee" and "Thou" are not archaic in Northern England, although "thou" is often corrupted to "tha". I can certainly imagine someone in Yorkshire saying "I'll see thee later" or "What's tha got in t'bag?"
"Thy" would be less common, but I doubt that it has died out entirely.  However, I can't imagine a typical Yorkshireman who would use "thee" and "thou" being sufficiently delicate as to use the word "thine".
I do agree with Janus though, that "art" is the verb required in "Who art thou?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment, Janus Bahs Jacquet wrote:

> *Thou* requires a specific form of the verb, which always ends in *-((e)s)t* (e.g., *thou art*, *thou wert*, *thou canst*, *thou thinkest*, etc.), so the first sentence is not grammatical. The rest are fine. Since they are so archaic, however, you should be aware that it’s frequently not just a matter of substituting one word for another – in order for it to seem natural, you’d have to emulate other grammatical features of older English as well, such as different vocabulary and inversion instead of *do*-support in questions (“Camest thou yestereve?” instead of “Did you come last night?”).

Answer (score 1):

In response to the first sentence…it could be used in Yorkshire with a slight change.
In the Rotherham area it would be ok to say, “Who-a’ thaaa?” The a’ being a contraction of are.
All the others are perfectly acceptable.
In response to a Yorkshireman not using the word thine, on the contrary it is also perfectly acceptable…however the sound might fluctuate depending on area from thine to thaaan.
This is based on my knowledge growing up in the Rotherham area from 1970-2002
Sorry to be a bit late t’t’ party!